# hover over one div, move another

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys. Basically I have a CSS triangle that I've created, and it sits along the base of a menu bar. What I'd like to do, is have the triangle slide to the underneath of a link in the menu bar if it's hovered over. I gave it a go myself using pure CSS, but I couldn't quite grasp it. Possibly it needs jQuery? Do you guys think you can crack it? Here's my JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/JE8kD/3/

Thanks as ever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/JE8kD/9/

Comment: :D might need some dinamic value for left but I think you'll handle that yourself.

Comment: Totally forgot about this - but if you're interested in seeing how it turned out so far: http://projects.beauaugust.co.uk/cheatulous/